# UITapGestureRecognizer does not cancel tap on UITableView elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have implemented UITableView where each cell contains some buttons
In order to detect if user taps on table I have added UITapGestureRecognizer.

I want the buttons in the cells to do nothing when user taps on them.
I have implemented this selector:

```
- (void) backgroundTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
  UIView *view = sender.view;
  NSLog(@"backgroundTouched %@", view);
}
```

I see that when I tap anywhere on the table this selector gets called except if I tap on any of the buttons contained in the UITableViewCell.

How can I avoid that?

Here is the code which creates the UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
pragma mark UISearchControllerDelegate

- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
  NSLog(@"didPresentSearchController");
  self.cancelGesture = [UITapGestureRecognizer new];
  [self.cancelGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTouched:)];
  self.cancelGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
  [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:self.cancelGesture];
}
```

Comment: Pl. clear your concern, you want to disable tap on table or button?

Comment: Disable button. Right now when I tap on button button action gets called and gesture selector does not.
I want the other way around

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your buttons to do anything, disable the userInteractionEnabled of the button.

```
cell.addCashButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: This works. Although it does not seem to me very elegant solution because I have to enable/disable for each cell depending on searchController is active or not

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Table has own touch action facility  use it's delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

And if you are using `UIButton` in custom cell then instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer` you can add button action method in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with button's `tag` like below

in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
[cell.yourButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(myButtonActionMethod:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

And declare button action method

```
-(void) myButtonActionMethod:(UIButton*)sender
 {
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button %@", sender.tag);
 }
```